# Scrolling MSVC text editor window horizontally one character at a time

Tags: visual-studio, text, scroll, ide, editor

I am able to scroll text vertically one line at a time by assigning WindowScrollUp / WindowScrollDown commands to Ctrl + Down Arrow / Ctrl + Up Arrow keys in Microsoft Visual Studio 97 IDE. But WindowScrollLeft / WindowScrollRight commands scroll the window horizontally one screen at a time. How could I scroll the text horizontally one character at a time? I was thinking of a macro where the caret jumps to the edge of the screen and then Right Arrow or Left Arrow is pressed, but the arrow keys cause the screen to scroll some distance horizontally that is much more than one character.